# jquery ajax getting variable from one function to another php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, function

So basically to give a brief before exploring in to the code I give below.
Basically what I'm trying to do is, I have a modal in one of my php page as below. I'm trying to show the model from a php function "fetch_assignment_history" given below. There is a button in which we can add users to the assignment, and the button onclick event(onClick="assign(this.dataset.id)") call function passing the id from the php function to JS function.

So when the user click the button the JS function shows the modal as well as get the assignment id in the function. This assignment id is set (through JS) to data attribute of multiple select dropdown in the modal.

Now the point where I'm stuck is, a setinterval constantly fetch the assigned users. This basically collect from mysql database of users who were added to the assignment (comma delimitted id's).

When the modal is opened I want the previously assigned users to be selected in the multiple select (as per data in mysql) as default. For this I want to get the id passed from the onclick event

My HTML part (modal)

```
<div id="assignee" class="modal custom-modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title text-center">Assignment</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-group has-feedback">
                                <label style="color:#333D79FF; font-size:15px;">Add Users <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                <div>
                                    <select class="select2_multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" id="userslist" name="userslist[]" style="width: 100%;left: 10px;">
                                        <option id="none" value="">Select Users</option>
                                            <?php
                                                My PHP CODE TO PULL OUT DATA FROM MYSQL DB
                                                ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-useravatar="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" data-usertitle="<?php echo $firstname;echo "&nbsp;";echo $lastname; ?>" data-role="<?php echo $role; ?>" data-assignment=""><?php echo $firstname;echo "&nbsp;";echo $lastname; ?></option>

                                            <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                              <div id="usersfetch"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My PHP 
1. function to fetch assignment history.
Below button onclick goes to JS and shows modal. and also pass id

```
function fetch_assignment_history($connect)
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM assignment 
    WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' 
    ORDER BY id ASC
    ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $user_name = '';
        $dynamic_background = '';
        $message = '';

                $assignmentname = $row["assignmentname"];
                $name = $row["name"];
                $id     = $row['id'];
        $output .= '

    <div class="x_panel" style=" font-size:14px;">
                    <span class="controlbuttons">
                        <button class="btn btn-round" data-id="'.$id.'" onClick="assign(this.dataset.id)"><i class="material-icons" title="Assign">person_add</i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>

        ';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
```

2. function to assigned user history

   ```
   function fetch_assigned_user_history($connect)
   {
   some php queries
   }
   ```

My JS

 I want the assignid from function assign(assignid) to be called from function fetch_assigned_user_history(). How do I accomplish this??????

```
setInterval(function(){
    fetch_assigned_user_history();
}, 1000);

function assign(assignid)
    {
        var assignid    = assignid;
        $("#assignee").modal("show");
        $('#userslist').data("assignment",assignid);

    }
function fetch_assigned_user_history()
    {
        var action = "fetch_assigned_user_data";
        var getid = ;// I need to get the ID from the previous function from onclick event function assign(assignid) 

        $.ajax({
            url:"assignment.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, assignmentid:getid},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#usersfetch').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

Hope I'm clear with my question. Appreciate for an advise to fix.
To summarise, the basic question is how to call variable of one JS function in to another (in this example id's) so that i can get the list of users in that assignment? Also how to get it selected by default the Multiple select with database values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already stored 'assignid' in data-* attribute, you can just retrieve it when you need it

```js
function assign(assignid) {
  var assignid    = assignid;
  $("#assignee").modal("show");
  
  // You already store your assignid at here
  $('#userslist').data("assignment",assignid);
}

function fetch_assigned_user_history()
    {
        var action = "fetch_assigned_user_data";
        
        // Now you just need to retrieve it
        var getid = $('#userslist').data("assignment");

        $.ajax({
            url:"assignment.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, assignmentid:getid},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#usersfetch').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I have assign data- attribute to the variable getid. Now when i do fetch, I'm getting php error Unidentified index:id. What to do.
I have assigned &_SESSION["id"]=&_POST["assignmentid"]; in the ajax post page

Comment: Should be $_SESSION["id"] = $_POST["assignmentid"] right? If not working then you have to check your PHP code